# Laravel BackPack CRUD select to show/change image

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to configure the select datafield on my backpack crud to show the stored image of my currently selected item.

I'm hoping its something small I'm overlooking, but I can't figure it out

I'm not sure if a custom field is the right way to go about it, but any help would be great

Comment: Hey Junior. 

There is not something like that built in core, sorry :-( 

You can create a custom field to meet your needs indeed, and I guess this is a good candidate for a custom field. 

Sorry I can't help much more here, wish you the best!

Comment: Hi, Junior,

Could you please mention more detail?

E.g., you wish to use blob to store the image? Or you wish to store the image as a file, and saving the filePath in the DB table?

Both of the above suggestions work, depends on your wish.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I ended up using the Backpack Crudfield Javascript Library
https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields-javascript-api

I was able to get the selected id and then I then added some ajax to grab the image from the database.